# MIPS OR logic and bit shifting

Tags: mips, bit-shift, logical-operators

If I call the two MIPs instructions

```
lui  $s0, 0x9344 //Load upper immediate
ori  $s0, $s0, 0xB01A //Logical Or Immediate
```

what is the value in $s0? Everytime I work it out I get the value 0x44B01A which I think is wrong.

Comment: How do you arrive at that value?

Comment: I think I added the wrong bits, is the correct answer 0x9344B01A

Comment: @BarneyChambers That looks about right.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sure, but I am doing it by hand so theres a large chance I'm wrong ;)

Comment: @BarneyChambers: You. It's simply appending the hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Is the value `0x44B01A` coming from MIPS or from your own calculation?

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen from my own (probably wrong) calculation